# How do I create 3D cylinder, sphere and cone using Actionscript 3 (Flash 10)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, 3d, flex4

I want to create a 3D cylinder, sphere, cone using Actionscript for Flash Player 10. Is there any available class?
I also want to know how to paint gradient, wrap text and texture around them. It would be nice if these class have these functions. I can't use non DisplayObject in this project so PV3D is not an option

Comment: Umm... there is no Actionscript 4 (yet). Typo?

Comment: Zevan: '+1' for making mistake, you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cameron says, you should probably use a framework like PV3D or Away3D. That said, all those frameworks are written in AS so you could roll your own.

Here are a few examples I created using only the fp10 3d engine:

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1726

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=2092

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=2097

http://actionsnippet.com/?p=2158

You can create primative shapes using parametric equations:

sphere :

```
x = r sin(u) cos(v)
y = r cos(u) cos(v)
z = r sin(v)
```

For a cylinder you can just use the equation for a circle and extrude it:

```
x = r cos(t)
y = r sin(t)
z = increase at some interval to the height of the cylinder
```

I can post some additional information about this topic if your interested.

Comment: Hm... I'm a bit confuse with your last part, "z = increase at some interval to the height of the cylinder" what is this "z" property? Which class does it belong to?

Answer (score 0):

There are [3D drawing functions](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/) for Flash 10, but I don't think they support wrapping text around a 3D object. It sounds like you need a 3D framework. Some popular ones (there's lots):

- [Sandy3D](http://www.flashsandy.org/)
- [Papervision3D](http://www.papervision3d.org/)
- [Away3D](http://away3d.com/)

Keep mind that Adobe has announced that it will soon be releasing a new version of Flash with built-in hardware-accelerated 3D rendering APIs (codenamed "[molehill](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flash/molehill/)").

Comment: you can do texture mapping and stuff with fp10 using drawTriangles and setting UV coordinates.

Comment: @Zevan: Yes, but I don't think you can do texture mapping with non-bitmaps, i.e. TextBoxes (like the OP wants)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I already experience with PV3D, but I have other constraint that requires me to uses native Flash.

Comment: @ohm: Hmm. What is "native Flash"? Surely anything written in AS3 counts?

Comment: @Cameron. If i understand correctly - you can map TextBoxes Videos and anything else that exists on the flash stage to a 3D object using drawTriangles. All you need to do is create a BitmapData object and draw the text, videos etc... to it using the draw() method.

Comment: @Zevan: That is what I understand also, though I thought you wanted the ability to have a dynamic textbox as a texture. You can of course draw anything to a bitmap and then use that as a texture.

Comment: @zevan by "native flash" I actually mean I have to stick with DisplayObject class for many reason. Lib such as pv3d haven't inherit its DisplayObject3D from flash's DisplayObject